# Get all nodes in a transitive relation

Tags: rdf, sparql

Is it somehow possible to get the list of nodes connected through a transitive relation with SPARQL?
I have elements that are connected in this way:

```
?a g:eastOf ?b
?b g:eastOf ?c
…
```

Not all nodes are connected with each other, because some are further down south. Only when nodes are vertically in the same plane there might be a `g:eastOf` relationship. This means there are several groups of nodes that are not connected with each other.

I'd like to get all these groups of nodes (basically a list of lists). Is there a way to do that in SPARQL? The `SELECT` statement requires a finite number of variables and can't somehow express "a list of" something.

I'm only interested in the lists where an `xsd:integer` property of all nodes is ascending when going from west to east, but that should be relatively easy after I have the solution for my first problem.

Comment: Now that SPARQL 1.1 is out, you can actually do this.  I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249277/1281433) showing how.  It should work with any SPARQL 1.1 engine.  I tested it with Jena, so [your constraint to use Jena](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056008/sparql-get-all-nodes-of-transient-relation/20249277#comment4360654_4057881) is not a problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can do at least some of this with SPARQL 1.1.

### Getting a list of nodes

Assume you have the data in which there are two groups of points that form a row based on `:eastOf`:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/>

:a :eastOf :b .
:b :eastOf :c .
:c :eastOf :d .

:e :eastOf :f .
:f :eastOf :g .
:g :eastOf :h .
```

Then you can use query like this:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/>

select (group_concat(strafter(str(?westernpoint),str(:));separator=", ") as ?colatitudinalPoints)
 where {
  ?easternmost :eastOf* ?westernpoint .
  filter not exists { ?easternmoster :eastOf ?easternmost }
}
group by ?easternmost
```

to get these results:

```
-----------------------
| colatitudinalPoints |
=======================
| "e, f, g, h"        |
| "a, b, c, d"        |
-----------------------
```

There's some string processing in

```
group_concat(strafter(str(?westernpoint),str(:));separator=", ") as ?colatitudinalPoints
```

that you might not need;  the point is that `?westernpoint` is the IRI of the points west of the east of the `?easternmost` (which actually includes `?easternmost`, since we used `*` in the property path), and then we need to concatenate those together somehow.  Here I did some string processing to make the results prettier.  You can just as easily do

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/>

select (group_concat(?westernpoint;separator=", ") as ?colatitudinalPoints)
 where {
  ?easternmost :eastOf* ?westernpoint .
  filter not exists { ?easternmoster :eastOf ?easternmost }
}
group by ?easternmost
```

and get

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| colatitudinalPoints                                                                                                                                                                      |
============================================================================================================================================================================================
| "http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/e, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/f, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/g, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/h" |
| "http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/a, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/b, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/c, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/1281433/d" |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Ensuring that the nodes are ascending

Your other requirement is a bit more of a challenge:

> I'm only interested in the lists where an xsd:integer property of all
>   nodes is ascending when going from west to east, but that should be
>   relatively easy after I have the solution for my first problem.

That said, if you can clarify exactly what you want in the case of something like

```
w --eastof-> x --eastof-> y --eastof-> z
|            |            |            |
5            6            2            3
```

E.g., do you want to reject the whole chain because the nodes aren't *all* ascending, or do you want to get the two subchains `w x` and `y z` wherein the values are ascending?  It might be possible to do both…

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't get a variable list of elements as an SPARQL solution. I think the easiest way to do what you need is just to get the pairs (a,b) from `?a g:eastOf ?b` and sort them.

```
SELECT ?a ?b WHERE {
?a g:eastOf ?b
} ORDER BY ASC(?a) ASC(?b)
```

It should be pretty straight forward to put some logic in place to convert the list of tuples on a list of elements.

If you use reasoning with transitivity you won't be able to trace back what's the path that connects A with C. In case you have something like (A,g:eastOf,B) and (B,g:eastOf,C). Basically in this case using reasoning will make the things more complicated because you want to construct the full list of connected elements. Transitivity in SPARQL will give you the *start* and *end* node but you'll loose traceability of all the intermediate points.

If you don't have millions of statements I think that the above SPARQL query plus some logic to transform the resultset will do the job.

**Edited to give pointers to Jena + owl:TransitiveProperty**

So first make sure that you load an ontology with the following axiom into your [Jena Model](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html):

```
g:eastOf rdf:type owl:TransitiveProperty .
```

Then enable the Jena OWL reasoner see documentation here :
[Jena OWL coverage](http://jena.sourceforge.net/inference/#owl)

And connect [Jena ARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/) to your model so to be able to launch SPARQL queries.

Once you've done that ... if you had something like ...

```
:x g:eastOf :y .
:y g:eastOf :t .
:t g:eastOf :z .
```

and you run a query like ...

```
SELECT ?a ?b WHERE {
?a g:eastOf ?b
} ORDER BY ASC(?a) ASC(?b)
```

you'll get ...

```
:x g:eastOf :y .
:x g:eastOf :t .
:x g:eastOf :z .
:y g:eastOf :t .
:y g:eastOf :z .
(...)
```

Also with Jena consider to use [Property Paths](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/property_paths.html). It'll do the job as well.

Let us know if its works or if you run into any issues, cheers !!!

Comment: "Transitivity in SPARQL will give you the start and end node but you'll loose traceability of all the intermediate points." Well this might be good enough because all nodes also have x and y coordinates and I could just sort them.

Comment: @panzi fair enough if Transitivity does the job and you have to use Jena then ... question edited to give you some pointers for that.

Comment: Property paths are part of sparql 1.1, btw. http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for adding the reference (+1)

Comment: Hm, the property paths are very handy indeed. However, is it somehow possible to add a restriction/condition that has to apply for each path element?

Comment: @panzi Do you recall what type of condition you were wondering about (I realize this is an older question.)  In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249277/1281433), you can see where you could add additional constraints on `?westernpoint` to get "a restriction/condition that has to apply for each path element".

Answer (score 0):

OpenLink Virtuoso supports such thing: [Transitivity in SPARQL](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfsparqlimplementatiotrans) This requires custom syntax in SPARQL queries.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Jena.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 now supports property paths, so you can do this with any current engine.