# SPARQL query results in Protege does not recognize transitive property

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, protege

I have almost the same requirement expresed in this question: [Get all nodes in a transitive relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056008/sparql-get-all-nodes-of-transient-relation)

I am using Protege 3.4.8. This is an Owl-Lite project.
I have a transitive property "contains", which is defined as an object property of type Node
Node has descendants of type A, B and C

I have individuals that link to each other through contains property like this:

A contains B contains C

When I run the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?A ?B
WHERE
{
    ?A :contains ?B         
}
```

I get :

```
A1 B1
B1 C1
```

Due to transitive nature of contains, I'd expect to get

```
A1 C1
```

too. 
What am I doing wrong here? The question I've linked to includes Jena in the answer, would it make a difference to do this on a Jena model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

Further searches led me to this page: http://opentox.org/data/documents/development/RDF%20files/JavaOnly/query-reasoning-with-jena-and-sparql

The following quote from this page (probably) explains the reasons behind the behaviour I'm seeing:

> "For our purposes SPARQL queries could be executed either directly
>   through the SPARQL query panel in Protege or from inside a JAVA
>   application using the specialised Jena library methods.  Both
>   approaches are able to handle queries concerning explicit object and
>   property relations but Jena libraries have the advantage of using a
>   reasoner. Thus queries executed using Jena library methods can return
>   results taking in account also the transitive and inferred relations."

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL is a RDF query language, so not all SPARQL engines should implement the OWL entailment (i.e., use OWL semantics for evaluating the query). Further details at http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/

Not sure which implementation is actually using Protege under the hood...