# Ontologies: Inferred superclass of individual

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege4

I am using Protege 4.3 (also tried the 5-beta) with the following simple ontology:

```
Class: Person


Class: Man

    SubClassOf: 
        Person


Individual: John

    Types: 
        Man
```

Next, I start the Reasoner Hermit 1.3.8, but John is not inferred to be a Person. Also the following SPARQL does not return anything:

```
PREFIX this: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2015/6/untitled-ontology-18#>

SELECT ?subject
    WHERE { ?subject a this:Person }
```

Do you have any suggestions what I understood wrong?

Comment: Okay, as for the SPARQL query, it seems like that Protege is not using a SPARQL implementation which makes use of a reasoner ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090299/sparql-query-results-in-protege-does-not-recognize-transitive-property) ). Using e.g. Jena should fix that. But first issue is still there.

Comment: Using Protege 5 with the _Snap SPARQL plugin_ solves the second issue, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the "missing" inference of subclass *Man* to superclass *Person*:

Protégé doesn't show individuals of a subclass in their superclass, even when the reasoner is active. The inference works, however, as you already saw. The following two examples both return **John** as an individual of class *Person*:

SPARQL + Reasoner (Snap SPARQL plugin 4.2.0 + HermiT 1.3.8.413)

```
PREFIX this: <urn:absolute:test#>

SELECT ?subject
    WHERE { ?subject a this:Person }
```

DL-Query + Reasoner (DL-Query 4.0.1 + HermiT 1.3.8.413)

```
Person
```

Another way to make it obvious is to export the ontology with all inferred axioms ("File" -> "Export inferred axioms as ontology..."). The resulting ontology contains two class assertions for **John**, one as *Man* and one as *Person*.

I assume this behaviour keeps the GUI usable when working with bigger ontologies, which might contain many individuals. As of Protégé 5.1.0, there seems to be no way to change this behaviour.